# Visualforce Page PDF table overflow

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I`m having some trouble with Visualforce Page render as PDF.

I need that the text still going bellow de image but breaks the line when touches it.

[image]

The line where its written "Partida do Motor Elétrico: Tubo Save (Inversor de
Frequência)" should continue til the right edge

I`ve written the structure using tag table as below

```
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela indexSize">{!item.tt_dados_1_index}.{! tt1.ind}</td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela justified">{!tt1.descricao}</td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela">{!item.translation.codigo}: {!tt1.codigo}</td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela">
                                    <table style="display: contents;">
                                        <apex:repeat value="{!tt1.desc_tec_formated}" var="desc_tecLines">
                                            <tr>
                                                <apex:repeat value="{!desc_tecLines}" var="desc_tec">
                                                    <td>
                                                        <p style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px">
                                                            {!desc_tec}
                                                        </p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </apex:repeat>
                                            </tr>
                                        </apex:repeat>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela">
                                    
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!tt1.configuracao_formated}" var="configuracao_formated">
                                        <p>
                                            {!configuracao_formated}
                                        </p>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela">
                                    
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!tt1.narrativa_formated}" var="narrativa">
                                        <p>
                                            {!narrativa}
                                        </p>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela">{!tt1.ncm}</td>
                                <td class="coluna-tabela"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <apex:variable var="foo" rendered="{!tt1.imgShow}" value="{!tt1}">
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <apex:image id="theImage" value="https://www.saur.com.br/imagens_orcamentos/{!tt1.imagem}" width="250px"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </apex:variable>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

[image]

I`m using two  tag to put image and text side by side, but this structure is not allowing me to keep the text til the edge.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, this isn't really a Visualforce/PDF issue, this is rather about using CSS and HTML to make the text flow around your image. The PDF renderer Visualforce uses is essentially just parsing the page's HTML + CSS and renders the PDF.
Check this for text/image alignments (answer by Danield): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179424/how-to-wrap-text-around-an-image-using-html-css

Comment: I was having trouble becouse the limitation of the pdf render. But I change the structure and follow your link tips and it worked. Thanks a lot!